# Android webview disable zoom icons

Tags: android, uiwebview, webview, zooming

I have a `webview` inside a `tabview` and have enabled the `zoomfunctions`. However, whenever I got back to the non-webview tab, the +/- icons are still displaying. Is there anyway to get rid of them or not make this happen? thanks

Comment: Have you solved this problem?? I have also got the same problem now

Answer (score 0):

you could disable `zoomfunctions` in the `onPause` of the `webview`

Comment: i did `@Override public void onPause(){mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false)}` and my app force closes. any ideas?

Comment: what is the stack trace on the fc?

Comment: make sure you have a "handle" on the mWebView before you try to "play" with it

Comment: Apologies for my ignorance and I am still learning android programming, but what do you mean a handle?

Comment: make sure it is not null ie mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(blahblahblah);

Comment: got it. Yeah no, it is not null.

Comment: what is the other view in the "non-webview" activity, what type of view is it

Comment: the other view is a just a regular `linear layout`

Comment: @mooongcle: Unfortunately i never solved the problem. I just disabled the zoom completely which was a bummer. Sorry I couldn't be much help. Let me know if you get it working.